# JavaScript - Promises - then

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I am trying to learn the concept of promises in JavaScript which will load the cdn link into the link tag using promises and accordingly return either resolve or reject callback.

```js
let loadURL = (href) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let newLink = document.createElement('link');
    newLink.href = href;
    document.body.appendChild(newLink);
    newLink.onload = () => {
      resolve(1);
    }
    newLink.onerror = () => {
      reject(0);
    }
  })
}

let p1 = loadURL("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
p1.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log("There is an Error " + error);
})
```

[image: Screenshot of console panel]

But above in my code **loadURL** function must return a resolve callback and it should execute the **then** part and print the value that the function is returning. But it is not going in that way also in my console panel I can't see neither the 'then' nor 'catch' part getting executed. Please help.

Help me to execute the 'then' part of the code :(

Comment: Please note that rejecting a promise doesn't call `catch`, it instead goes into `then`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject

Comment: Also, I don't think link elements can go inside `body`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox — Rejecting a promise doesn't go into `then` *or* `catch`. Those are the methods used to bind event listeners for promise resolve or rejections. While you can, as per the example you link to, register a rejection callback with the second argument to `then`, you **can** also use `catch` as this question does.

Answer (score 2):

A `link` element with an `href` attribute alone **won't load anything**.

The `then` callback doesn't run because the promise never resolves because the `load` event never fires because you haven't constructed a `link` that will load anything.

A stylesheet `link` will only load when you include `rel="stylesheet"`.

Comment: ```
newLink.rel= "stylesheet";
```

I added this line and it worked.
Thank you for your contribution :)